# Nested table usage in Oracle DB, PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, foreign-keys

I have a nested table `nt` and a database table `fruits`.  I would like to have all elements of `nt` in table `fruits`.  Is there some kind of bulk insert method for collections that could be cheaper than looping through each element?

Also, let's say I have a parent table `food` with column `fruit_id`.  Is having the child table `fruits` ideal?  Is storing the collection directly into the table `food` by creating a type `food_type` more efficient?

---

- Current Design:

**Parent Table:** food; **columns:** `id`, `name`, `fruit_id`

**Child Table:** fruits; **columns:** `id`,`name` where
nested table `nt` is inserted into child table `fruits` via loop

- Proposed Design:

**Table:** food; **columns:** `id`, `name`, `fruit_table`
where

```
CREATE type food_type IS TABLE OF varchar(50);
nt food_type;
```

and `nt` is inserted with the row, as part of column `fruit_table`

Comment: i think you can use a before/after insert trigger.
i.e when you insert in the table nt, the elements will be inserted in the table fruits after or before the insert.
if you could show the structure of your tables, it would be easier.

Comment: What is your current database design? Would you please provide a graphical or textual interpretation?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can do that using following insert statement:

   ```
   INSERT INTO fruits (id, name) 
   select fruit_sequence_name.nextval, COLUMN_VALUE from TABLE(nt);
   ```
2. It depends on queries you are going to run. If you need do a lot of analytical queries it makes sense to separate those, otherwise there is no problem to store nested table inside foods.